# Can't figure out NameError

Tags: python, nameerror

I am trying to build a cost model using mostly if statements but I keep getting the error:

```
NameError: name 'spread_1' is not defined.
```

I am a beginner with python so I don't know if I've done something incorrect. Please help.

```
#water depth of project site in metres
water_depth = 100

#platform wells require jackups
pl = 1
#1-2 complexity required LWIV
ss_simple = 1
#3-4 complexity requires rig
ss_complex = 0

#day rates
vjackup = 75000
jackup = 90000
vsemi = 170000
semi = 300000
lwiv = 200000

#determining vessel spread for platform wells
if pl >= 1:
    if water_depth == range(0, 50):
        spread_1 = vjackup * 24.1
    elif water_depth == range(51, 150):
        spread_1 = jackup * 24.1
elif pl == 0:
    spread_1 = 0
```

Comment: What if pl is not 0 neither is equal or greater than 1. For example pl == 0.5?

Comment: pl is number of wells so can only be 0 or a number equal or greater than 1

Comment: `spread_1` is never set because `water_depth == range(...)` is checking whether `water_depth` is a `range` object with the same bounds, not whether it is within the bounds.  See the linked duplicate for how to check correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `==` with `in` at the

```
if water_depth == range(0, 50):
```

and

```
elif water_depth == range(51, 150):
```

making your block of code:

```
if pl >= 1:
    if water_depth == range(0, 50):
        spread_1 = vjackup * 24.1
    elif water_depth == range(51, 150):
        spread_1 = jackup * 24.1
elif pl == 0:
    spread_1 = 0
```

into

```
if pl >= 1:
    if water_depth in range(0, 50):
        spread_1 = vjackup * 24.1
    elif water_depth in range(51, 150):
        spread_1 = jackup * 24.1
elif pl == 0:
    spread_1 = 0
```

But it would be more practical to use extreme equality operators in your case:

```
if pl >= 1:
    if 0 <= water_depth < 50:
        spread_1 = vjackup * 24.1
    elif 51 <= water_depth < 150:
        spread_1 = jackup * 24.1
elif pl == 0:
    spread_1 = 0
```

Do note that the `range()` function omits the end value, so `range(0, 50)`'s last value would be `49`, not `50`.